# How to sort AJAX results using toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ebay-api

I have made an AJAX request that fetches completed Ebay auction results using Ebay's API (Finding Service).  It works, producing the desired results, but now I am a stuck on how best to filter those results (in my case, using a button) by price, date of sale, etc.

For example:  I have the variable `url` which has the filter `url += "&sortOrder=StartTimeNewest";`. I would like a button to toggle between that filter and `url += "&sortOrder=StartTimeOldest";` using a click event.

I am a student, and pretty inexperienced when it comes to JS/frameworks...and so far have not had much luck figuring out the best way to do this aside from duplicating my entire code from `ebay.js` and altering it slightly for each filter I would like to apply.

For example: I can create different variables like `url1`, `url2` and so on that have the filters I want, calling them from a different ajax requests attached to the buttons...

...but I'm sure there is a better and simpler way to do this without being so repetitive and would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Ebay.js

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('form[role="search"]').submit(function(ev)  {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var searchstring = $('input[type="text"]', this).val();

    var url = "https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
    url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems";
    url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0";
    url += "&SERVICE-NAME=FindingService";
    url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=BrandonE-DigIt-PRD-5cd429718-3d6a116b";
    url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
    url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
    url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
    url += "&itemFilter(0).name=MinPrice";
    url += "&itemFilter(0).value=7.00";
    url += "&itemFilter(0).paramName=Currency";
    url += "&itemFilter(0).paramValue=USD";
    url += "&paginationInput.pageNumber=1";
    url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50";
    url += "&keywords=" + searchstring;
    url += "&sortOrder=StartTimeNewest";
    url += "&categoryId=176985";

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
        var items = res.findCompletedItemsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item;
        var ins = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
          ins += "<div>";
          ins += "<img src='" + items[i].galleryURL + "  '/>";
          ins += "  " + items[i].title + " - ";
          ins += "Sold for $" + items[i].sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__;
          ins += "</div><br />";
        };
        $('.results').html(ins);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button id="mainbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>

<div class="filters col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-offset-md-1">
  <!-- TOGGLE BUTTONS WILL ALLOW RESULTS TO BE SORTED. -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm date-btn">date</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm price-btn">price</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="index col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-offset-md-1">
  <p class="restitle">results:</p><br />
  <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add a `data-price` and a `data-date`attribute on the parent container of each result. Your toggle button will look for all of those. Using a sort function, you will rearrange the DOM.

Comment: ok...so if I understand you correctly, I wouldn't be altering the ajax request necessarily.  I'd just be re-ordering the same results?  It still seems like I'd have to alter the `url` variable somehow to make certain filters work.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I mean **if the query has not changed**, then making a call to the server is a waste of data. Another approach is to save the most recent query results into a variable. When you have to filter the results, just use an `array.sort()` function on the variable. Then rerender your data on dom using JS.  It should be faster than a new ajax call.

Comment: Now that I look at the URL params a little more. I see that the API is using paging. In this case, you will have to do another ajax call updating the `sortOrder` param. You will have to look at the API and see how eBay expects you to query by ascending or descending and if you can pass multiple variables in. https://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/product/CallRef/types/SortOrder.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Yeah, after playing around a bit, that's kind of what I'm thinking.  With all of those url params in place, the only way I can visualize this working is by making another ajax call using the relevant params in a different url for each button.  Just have to now figure out how to have the button trigger a new request while keeping the original keyword/search params from the form in place.

Answer (score 1):

Per our comments, I created a simple class that will generate the url for you. 
Go ahead and tweek it to get the correct values in there. Hopefully this helps!

I added comments in the code but lmk if you have any questions.

```js
$(function() {

  // invoke click event
  $("[data-filter]").off();
  $("[data-filter]").on("click", function() {
    let $this = $(this);
    let data = $this.data();
    // toggle value
    if (data.value == false) {
      $(this).data("value", true);
    } else {
      $(this).data("value", false);
    }

    // create class
    let url = new buildfindCompletedItemsUrl();

    // get the sort order
    url.getSortOrder();

    // build the url
    let ajaxUrl = url.build();

    // get the results
    GetFilteredResults(ajaxUrl, function(results) {
      $("body").append($("<p />", {
        text: results
      }));
    })
  });
})


// class with contructor
function buildfindCompletedItemsUrl() {
  this.url = "https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
  this.defaultUrlParams = {
    "OPERATION-NAME": "findCompletedItems",
    "SERVICE-VERSION": "1.13.0",
    "SERVICE-NAME": "FindingService",
    "SECURITY-APPNAME": "BrandonE-DigIt-PRD-5cd429718-3d6a116b",
    "GLOBAL-ID": "EBAY-US",
    "RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON",
    "REST-PAYLOAD": "",
    "itemFilter(0).name": "MinPrice",
    "itemFilter(0).value": "7.00",
    "itemFilter(0).paramName": "Currency",
    "itemFilter(0).paramValue": "USD",
    "paginationInput.pageNumber": "1",
    "sortOrder": "",
    "paginationInput.entriesPerPage": "50",
    "categoryId": "176985"
  }
  return this;
}

// looks at the dom and fills the sortOrderParam
buildfindCompletedItemsUrl.prototype.getSortOrder = function() {
  var $filters = $("[data-filter]");
  let param = this.defaultUrlParams["sortOrder"];
  let _ = this;
  $.each($filters, function(i, f) {
    let $filter = $(f);
    let data = $filter.data();
    let val = data.value;
    if (val == true) {
      if (_.defaultUrlParams["sortOrder"] == "") {
        _.defaultUrlParams["sortOrder"] += data.filter;
      } else {
        _.defaultUrlParams["sortOrder"] += "," + data.filter;
      }
    }
  })
};

// builds the full url for the ajax call
buildfindCompletedItemsUrl.prototype.build = function() {
  let _url = this.url;
  let keys = Object.keys(this.defaultUrlParams);
  let length = keys.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let key = keys[i];
    let val = this.defaultUrlParams[key];
    if (i == 0) {
      _url += `?${key}=${val}`;
    } else {
      _url += `&${key}=${val}`;
    }
  }
  return _url;
}


// get your results and return them
function GetFilteredResults(url, callback) {
  // do ajax here 
  return callback(url)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-filter="date" data-value="false">Sort By Date</button>
<button data-filter="price" data-value="false">Sort By Price</button>
```

Comment: Oh wow...thanks Christian.  I didn't expect you to put in that much work, so it's appreciated.  I will see if this will work when I get home.  I'm sure this will at the very least get my close.